# Convert from SimpleTest to PHPUnit $this->UnitTestCase('message .....');

Tags: php, phpunit, simpletest

Which action/method is in PHPUnit equal to in simpleTest:

```
$this->UnitTestCase('message .....')
```

***Edit: Sorry for my mistake***

---

I think what I asking about not exist in simple test directly its just our extended class.

**But this method display message in begining of test- how its done with PHPUnit?**

Thanks

Comment: I've checked the docs, and can't find that method (I didn't look very hard)...  I see a class by that name, but not a method... What does it do?

Comment: @ircmaxell: I had the same trouble, and my best guess is this: http://www.simpletest.org/api/SimpleTest/UnitTester/UnitTestCase.html#__construct

Comment: @Tim, you can't call `__construct` by the class name.  You would need to call `parent::__construct` (I've tried it).  So if that's the class that `$this` inherits from, then there is no `UnitTestCase` method (as far as I can tell)...  Which is what's really puzzling about this question...

Comment: Funny, it's shown [here](http://www.simpletest.org/en/group_test_tutorial.html#another) but there is neither a method of that name in [UnitTestCase](http://simpletest.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/simpletest/simpletest/trunk/unit_tester.php?revision=1999&view=markup), nor in [SimpleTestCase](http://simpletest.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/simpletest/simpletest/trunk/test_case.php?revision=1999&view=markup), nor do they define any `__call` or `__invoke` magic methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a SimpleTest expert, but as far as I can tell that's the constructor for the UnitTestCase class. The equivalent in PHPUnit is PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase; you create your own tests by subclassing that and defining test methods. See [the PHPUnit docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) on writing tests for a quick howto and more info, but briefly, this is a complete PHPUnit test:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testSomething {
        $this->assertTrue(MyClass::getSomethingTrue());
    }
}
```

**Update:** to answer the revised question, the primary way to display messages in PHPUnit is on assertion failure. Every `assert*` function comes with an optional `$message` argument at the end, which you can use to display a custom message when that assertion fails.

If you want to *always* display a message, without having to fail an assertion, then you might try a straightforward `print` statement. It'll be interspersed with the test output, so this may not be the best (or nicest-looking) way of accomplishing what you want, but it'll certainly dump text to a console, which is what you seem to be asking.

If you're looking for some advanced debugging during unit-testing, you may also want to consider a logging framework of some kind (or even just a custom function that opens a file, prints to it, and closes the file again). That way, you preserve the integrity of the test output, but still get extra custom messages wherever you want them during your tests.